# Is there a better tool to manage LINQ2SQL DataContext files?

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a rather large LINQ2SQL for a project that I am working on.  I must confess that I primarily use the WYSIWYG editor provided by Visual Studio to manage and build the structure.  I am starting to run into a problem when it comes to locating entities on the diagram and just working with it in general.

Is there a better WYSIWYG tool -- better than the one provided by Visual Studio -- out there that can assist in the management of the LINQ2SQL dbml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any alternatives unfortunately for the linq2sql designer.

EDIT:

Further thought on this since comments....

While not a WYSIWYG you could look into SQL Metal (cmd line) to generate/work with the linq2sql generated files.

It does have an open source UI for it now also.

Check out http://csainty.blogspot.com/2008/02/linq-to-sql-sqlmetalexe.html for some info on it.

Comment: He asked if there was a better WYSIWYG Tool for the L2S Diagram in VS.  I have not found an alternative to this particular question.  How is my answer not an answer?  I am telling him that I have not found an alternative to his question.  He didn't ask if there was a better IDE to design the database as you suggested with the altova product.  He didn't ask about an alternative to Linq2SQL as you listed with the Entity Framework.  Although, my answer is perhaps not what he wanted to hear, is an answer none-the-less.  There exists no alternative to the L2S designer in VS.

Comment: (+1) It is an answer ... just maybe not one I want to hear! =)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the WYSIWYG tool just to build database structures, you might want to move over to using the "[Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427(VS.80).aspx)" and use [some other tool](http://www.altova.com/databasespy.html) to design the database structure.

Comment: I'll be honest, not sure how much time would be lost moving to the Entity Framework.

Comment: I'll be honest too. I can't estimate this either because it depends on the amount of code you already have. Still, the suggested tool (second link) might be useful for designing the database.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give some serious thought to how you are approaching this problem.  There may be commercial products out there that meet your needs, but there isn't anything freely available that comes even close.  I haven't seen any clear reviews of commercial tools in this regard.

The Linq2Sql O/R Designer doesn't scale, as you've unfortunately found out the hard way.  Something like SQLMetal will scale much better, but it's not a perfect solution either.

Unfortunately, it can be very painful to switch from using the O/R Designer to SQLMetal as they don't share as much code underneath the covers as you would hope.

If you are trying to use a large database with Linq2Sql, you almost have to find and adopt a commercial tool of some sort.  One free option worth considering is [Damien Guard's LinqToSql T4 Templates](http://l2st4.codeplex.com/), but it's not even close to a WYSIWYG tool.

Switching to a more capable ORM is also going to be difficult.

I wrote a blog entry on this subject some time ago and I've rehashed a lot of this already in this answer:

[Do not use the Visual Studio 2008 LinqToSql O/R Designer](http://www.capprime.com/software_development_weblog/PermaLink,guid,f1a9b52c-b407-4cbb-9197-4bae289ae11d.aspx)

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my add-in at http://www.huagati.com/dbmltools/

It does not replace the designer, but it adds a pile of missing functionality to the designer, so it makes the designer easier to use.

Comment: This is a commercial product.

Comment: Eh, yes it is.

I can't see anywhere that the OP ask for free tools only..?

Comment: I was just trying to save the OP some time if they were confused on that point.  Sometimes commercial products aren't an option and it's always nice to know up front.  I personally don't have a problem with people marketing products on SO.

Comment: Ok. Anyway, it is free to use for the first 45 days (45-day trial) so plenty of time to evaluate if it is worth using or not...